Blocking specific token program's TXs
As a validator, how do you block a specific token program's txs?

This is going out a bit on a limb, but you should be able to do this by modifying banking stage by hand on your validator.
You can add a new packet filter to filter out transactions that contain the program id that you want to avoid at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/150f4d7103fb4d9d8bffde0bef2201fbb4ce7bf7/core/src/banking_stage/packet_filter.rs#L22
And then you can call that new filter at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/150f4d7103fb4d9d8bffde0bef2201fbb4ce7bf7/core/src/banking_stage/packet_receiver.rs#L53
But note that this will only take effect when your validator is the leader, and not when replaying. Otherwise, your node will not be able to properly participate in consensus.
